# Steam didn't change language. After a reinstall, it doesn't even open

Tags: steam, macos

I use Steam in English, but I first installed it in Spanish. Yesterday, it randomly changed back to Spanish and wouldn't change to any other language, even after restarting. Today, I decided to replace the app with a brand new one from the English installer. The new app gets me a prompt saying: “The app ‘Steam’ can't be opened.”. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Did the installer download properly? Have you tried redownloading it?

Comment: Yes, I did download it twice. The result was the exact same.

Comment: AFAIK language files will be downloaded after changing the client language. Maybe the download/check of those files failed.

Comment: I tried about a dozen times, even once in another language just to see if it was just English. But it wasn't just that. Steam refused to change even after restart.

Comment: What error code are you getting? There should be a number after the error you're getting.

Comment: None, because it's an OS prompt, not a Steam one.

Comment: The OS prompt should still have a number, like [this one does](http://i.imgur.com/WaN60yV.jpg).

Comment: @eijen [This one](http://imgur.com/yGhpAIn) doesn't have a code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a guide in the Steam forums: http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/2/458604254461190576/

It seems that a restart should cut it. If not, renaming the app. If not, removing only the app, inputing steam://flushconfig in Safari, restarting and reinstalling the app will cut it for sure.

Answer (score -1):

What I'm suggesting to do is extreme but may solve the problem. However, you'll want to back up your data first in case it doesn't work.

Since there's no error code for the error you're getting I'm suggesting the simplest thing possible that might fix it: actually deleting Steam's data storage. What you can't see right now is that Steam actually stores stuff inside a folder called **Library** in your home folder. I'm not sure what this is called in Spanish in this case, so I'll be assuming you can do the translation yourself.

To get there, press Command-Shift-G on an open Finder window and type in **~/Library**. Once there, navigate to **Application Support** and you'll see a folder named **Steam**.

Delete the **entire folder** and re-install Steam. This will mean you have to re-install your games if re-installing Steam works, but your saves should be safe since they tend to be stored elsewhere.

Comment: or just remove everything in Steam folder except steamapps folder to keep your games.

Comment: I know about Application Support, and deleting the entire Steam folder doesn't do anything. It's definetely an OS error.

Comment: @inakilbss Have you tried restarting? Sometimes doing something simple like that will fix the problem.

Comment: Have you read my answer?

Comment: My bad, I missed it. This just seems like a mystery to me, honestly. The only other thing I can think of is check Activity Monitor to see if anything weird is going on there.